# Is there a way to stop Unity from automatically adding packages to a project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently come back to working on a Unity project after about a month. When I loaded my project I noticed that it seems that Unity has added a bunch of packages. I don't necessarily want all of these-- they're taking up space, not to mention some come with sprites I don't want that are cluttering up the project. Apparently Unity insists on doing this with every project opened, since I tried loading older projects and they had the same problem. Is there a way to stop Unity from automatically adding packages, or do I just have to delete them manually? I have poked around the package manager and it has no evident way to do this.

Comment: I don't recall Unity ever adding a package to an older project for me. Did you open an old project with a newer version of Unity? That could do it if a prerequisite has changed or a package update added a prerequisite. You can always use the package manager to remove things. Use the dropdown at the top to select Unity Registry or Built-In if you don't see what you want to remove then click it and there should be a remove/disable button. You may need to remove a feature set or dependency first.

Comment: No, I used the same version as always for it. I've been able to remove them just fine, I just wondered if there was a way to stop this from happening. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Project Folder (the one above the Asset folder), there is a folder `Packages` and there is a file `manifest.json` in it. If you open this file you will see the unity registered packages that will be automatically added to your project.

This is the file the unity editor looks for while auto downloading / updating packages.

Add / remove lines in this file to get the result you need. Note: be careful and make a backup before you make any modifications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. Is it possible to change the default packages that automatically appear in manifest.json? I'd prefer not to have to edit the file any time I make a new project. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, not that i know of. The solution I see people do is they have a custom editor script and switch the manifest.json file to their need with a click of a button after the new project is created.